# ee.Image.sample not working with Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

I am using *ee* and *geemap* in a *conda* environment running *Python 3.9.16* and am trying to sample a raster, i.e. convert image pixels to features. This is a [documentation example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-sample) translated into Python.
Unfortunately, no matter what geometry is used, an error is thrown

> EEException: Invalid GeoJSON geometry.

Using `sampleRegion(...)` instead I am getting

> EEException: Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: {'region': , 'geometries': True}

What is causing the problem?

```
import ee
import geemap
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# Demonstrate extracting pixels from an image as features with
# ee.Image.sample(), and show how the features are aligned with the pixels.

# An image with one band of elevation data.
image = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4')
VIS_MIN = 1620
VIS_MAX = 1650
Map.addLayer(image, {'min': VIS_MIN, 'max': VIS_MAX}, 'SRTM')

# Region to sample.
region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.006, 40.002],
    [-110.006, 39.999],
    [-109.995, 39.999],
    [-109.995, 40.002]]], None, False)
# Show region on the map.
Map.setCenter(-110, 40, 16)
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection([region]).style(**{"color": "00FF0022"}))

# Perform sampling; convert image pixels to features.
samples = image.sample({
  'region': region,

  # Default (False) is no geometries in the output.
  # When set to True, each feature has a Point geometry at the center of the
  # image pixel.
  'geometries': True,

  # The scale is not specified, so the resolution of the image will be used,
  # and there is a feature for every pixel. If we give a scale parameter, the
  # image will be resampled and there will be more or fewer features.
  #
  # scale: 200,
})

# Visualize sample data using ee.FeatureCollection.style(**).
styled = samples

def func_uiv (feature):
    return feature.set('style', {
      'pointSize': feature.getNumber('elevation').unitScale(VIS_MIN, VIS_MAX) \
          .multiply(15),
    }) \
  .map(func_uiv) \
  .style(**{
    'color': '000000FF',
    'fillColor': '00000000',
    'styleProperty': 'style',
    'neighborhood': 6,  # increase to correctly draw large points
  })
Map.addLayer(styled)

# Each sample feature has a point geometry and a property named 'elevation'
# corresponding to the band named 'elevation' of the image. If there are
# multiple bands they will become multiple properties. This will print:
#
# geometry: Point (-110.01, 40.00)
# properties:
#   elevation: 1639
print(samples.first())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a javascript v.s. python argument passing issue.  You're passing a single positional argument (a dict) to `image.sample` instead of the required positional or keyword arguments.

So `image.sample` is trying to use the entire dict (below) as the `region` argument and that's not a valid GeoJSON/`ee.Geometry.Polygon` object:

```
{
  'region': region,
  'geometries': True,
}
```

Instead, you can use keyword args

```
samples = image.sample(region=region, etc...)
```

Or dict unpacking (`**kwargs`) to create keyword args from the dict

```
samples = image.sample(**{
  'region': region, 
  etc...
})
```